# Can I add a clicklistener to LinearLayout in Android?

Tags: android, event-handling, android-linearlayout

I want to do something when the user clicks on the LinearLayout group.

Comment: 45 questions! Come on you are more of a pro than I am! haha

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can. Just use `android:onClick="methodName"` or add it programatically by using `setOnClickListener`